# an issue in getting the date for the posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is my index.php code

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php 
        if (have_posts()) {
            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post(); 
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="main-post">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                <a href="<?php get_the_author_link() ?>"><span class="author"><i class="ion-android-person"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span></a>
                <span class="date"><i class="ion-ios-clock"></i><?php the_date('F j, Y'); ?></span>
                <span class="comments"><i class="ion-chatbubble-working"></i>20 comments</span>
                <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://placehold.it/600x200/555" alt="">
                <p class="post-content">Mouth. It when to finds at should, for queen more uninitiated to what are negotiations the reached understood. Making to company, it's musical for notice and with are he my size all having bad completely ran explain right the counter-productive like in just energetic other misleads brains the to more.</p>
                <hr>
                <p class="categories"><i class="ion-pricetag"></i><?php the_category(', ') ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            } // end while
        } // end if
        ?>
    </div><!-- end row-->
</div><!--end container-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is what I'm getting in the browser:

[image: the posts in the browser]

My question is: why is the date only appearing in the first post?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript in WP using `the_*` function `echo` itself with in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
<span class="date">
    <i class="ion-ios-clock"></i><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?>
</span>
```

Instead of this:

```php
<span class="date">
    <i class="ion-ios-clock"></i><?php the_date('F j, Y'); ?>
</span>
```

#### Explanation

*The below explanation is not my own; it is by kaiser - [WPDSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376483/kaiser).*

When you look at the source of the [`the_date()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_date/) function, then you will notice two globals:

```
global $currentday, $previousday;
```

And then there's a rule if there's a date to display ... or not. The check is similar to the one done with [`is_new_day()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fb019893f983ff47d7d92e93e08ffbe979ebaafb/wp-includes/functions.php#L635-L652):

```
if ( $currentday != $previousday ) {

    // show date

    // Set global
    $previousday = $currentday;
}
// else
return null;
```

As you can see, the `$previousday` instantly gets set to `$currentday;`. So it gets echo-ed once. Right after that, both days are the same and the check will fail. That's the reason why your first post displays it, but the others don't show it.

---

Reference: [Post doesn't show date if there's another post with the same date](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166766/140731)